# Atascado con Hibernate. "object is not an instance of declaring class"

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

Ando intentando hacer un ejercicio de clase y soy incapaz de dar con la solución a este error.
Estamos trabajando con Hibernate y a la hora de hacer una relación one-to-one, me lanza una excepción cuya causa es *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class*

Se supone que tal y como tengo el código, tendría que coger el valor de la columna **cif** de **Empresa** en la base de datos y relacionarlo con la columna **cif** de la tabla **Direccion**, pero no se en que punto no coge los parámetros. En las tablas de la BBDD el valor es un int, con lo que no me cuadra que le devuelva otro tipo de objeto.

(Disculpad por todo el rollazo pero no entiendo muy bien en que punto estoy fallando y ya son un par de días dándole vueltas U__U)

Esta es la clase principal:

```
public class HolaMundoDeHibernate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction(); 
    Empresa e = new Empresa();
    e.setNombre("un nombre");
    e.setEmpleados(1);
    e.setDireccion("una direccion");
    e.setDirecc(new Direccion("una calle","un sitio",34532));

    session.save(e);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

La clase Empresa:

```
public class Empresa {

private int cif;
private String nombre;
private int empleados;
private String direccion;

private Set<Pedido> pedido = new HashSet<Pedido>();

private Direccion direcc;

public Empresa(){
    setDirecc(new Direccion());
}


public Direccion getDirecc() {
    return direcc;
}


public void setDirecc(Direccion direcc) {
    this.direcc = direcc;
    direcc.setEmpresa(this);
}

public Set<Pedido> getPedido() {
    return pedido;
}
public void setPedido(Set<Pedido> pedido) {
    this.pedido = pedido;
}
public int getCif() {
    return cif;
}
public void setCif(int cif) {
    this.cif = cif;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public int getEmpleados() {
    return empleados;
}
public void setEmpleados(int empleados) {
    this.empleados = empleados;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}
public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public void addPedido(Pedido pedido){
    pedido.setEmpresa(this);
    this.pedido.add(pedido);
}
```

}

La clase Direccion:

```
public class Direccion {

private int cif;
private String calle;
private String poblacion;
private int cp;
private Empresa empresa;

public Direccion(){

}

public Direccion(String calle,String poblacion, int cp){
    super();
    this.calle = calle;
    this.poblacion = poblacion;
    this.cp = cp;

}

public String getCalle() {
    return calle;
}

public void setCalle(String calle) {
    this.calle = calle;
}

public int getCif() {

    return cif;
}

public void setCif(int cif) {
    this.cif = cif;
}

public String getPoblacion() {
    return poblacion;
}

public void setPoblacion(String poblacion) {
    this.poblacion = poblacion;
}

public int getCp() {
    return cp;
}

public void setCp(int cp) {
    this.cp = cp;
}

public Empresa getEmpresa() {
    return empresa;
}

public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
    this.empresa = empresa;
}
}
```

El xml de mapeo de Empresa:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="programa.Empresa" table="EMPRESA">
    <id name="cif" type="int">
        <column name="CIF" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="nombre" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="NOMBRE" />
    </property>
    <property name="empleados" type="int">
        <column name="EMPLEADOS" />
    </property>
    <property name="direcc" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="DIRECCION" />
    </property>

    <many-to-one name="direccion" class="programa.Direccion" column="CIF_EMPRESA" unique="true"/>

    <set name="pedido" table="PEDIDO_EMPRESA" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
        <key>
            <column name="CIF" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="programa.Pedido" />
    </set>
</class>
```

y el xml de mapeo de Dirección:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="programa.Direccion" table="DIRECCION">
    <id name="cif" type="int">
        <column name="CIF" />
        <generator class="increment">
            <param name="property">empresa</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="calle" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="CALLE" />
    </property>
    <property name="poblacion" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="POBLACION" />
    </property>
    <property name="cp" type="int">
        <column name="CP" />
    </property>
    <one-to-one name="empresa" class="programa.Empresa" property-ref="cif"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Empresa tienes

```
private String direccion;
...
private Direccion direcc;
```

y en el mapeo XML tienes

```
<property name="direcc" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="DIRECCION" />
</property>

<many-to-one name="direccion" class="programa.Direccion" column="CIF_EMPRESA" unique="true"/>
```

Es decir, tienes los tipos cruzados.

Te aconsejo que uses anotaciones en lugar de un XML para mapear, es más fácil de mantener porque sólo tienes que cambiar en un sitio. y es más difícil perder la consistencia.

Comment: No te puedes ni imaginar lo estúpido que me estoy sintiendo en este momento. Ya lo tengo todo arreglado. ¡¡Muchísimas gracias!!.

En cuanto a lo del mapeo, ahora en el curso estamos mirándolo con XML, no se si miraremos el uso de anotaciones pero me lo pongo en la lista de cosas pendientes a mirar.

De nuevo, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Te aseguro que me lo puedo imaginar, me he pegado dos días atascado con esta [tontería](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096490/cannot-populate-form-controls-from-controller?noredirect=1#comment95025688_54096490)

Comment: Además, es una excelente primera cuestión, has puesto todo lo necesario de tu escenario para poder ver el error y solucionarlo, no te creas que es algo común

Comment: Los mismos dos días que llevaba yo con mi tontería...
Lo mejor es que después de tu solución me había salido otro problema, pero con este he dado en seguida. Y gracias por lo del detalle. Me ha faltado pegar la excepción, pero bueno, a ver si algún día llego a poder solucionarle a alguien las cosas por aquí :)